# Подпись .apk файла программно

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно программно подписать .apk файл используя библиотеку zipsigner-lib. Пересмотрел несколько примеров в гугле - один и тот же результат: создавался отдельный .apk файл, содержащий только папку META-INF, а мне нужно, чтобы META-INF создавался в заранее наполненом apk. Для подписи использовал следующий код:

```
private void signAPK() {

try {
    String generatedApkPath = GENERATE_APK_TO_DIRECTORY + apkname + ".apk";

    String signedApkPath = GENERATE_APK_TO_DIRECTORY + apkname + "-signed.apk";
    Log.i("Sign APK", "Going to create signed apk in:" + signedApkPath);

    ZipSigner zipSigner = null;
    zipSigner = new ZipSigner();

    zipSigner.setKeymode("testkey");

    zipSigner.signZip(generatedApkPath, signedApkPath);

    // After signing apk , delete unsigned apk
    new File(generatedApkPath).delete();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "'" + apkname + "-signed.apk' is generated at " + GENERATE_APK_TO_DIRECTORY, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();

} catch (Throwable t) {
    Log.e("Signing apk", "Error while signing apk to external directory", t);
    t.printStackTrace();
} }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это осуществить?